# posting on the facebook page

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

I am using this code to post any text on the facebook page with the page id menetioned in the code. it gives success message but when i goto the page there is nothing.
Pls help...

Thanks in advance

```
-(void)facebookPost;
```

{
    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
    FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc]init]; //initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gg"]];
    //finally, set the FbGraphFileobject onto our variables dictionary....
    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];

```
[variables setObject:@"hihihi" forKey:@"message"];
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/167884363345570/feed",FACEBOOK_APP_KEY] withPostVars:variables];
```

FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/167884363345570/feed",FACEBOOK_APP_KEY] withPostVars:variables];

```
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in this line...

**wrong:**

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/167884363345570/feed",FACEBOOK_APP_KEY] withPostVars:variables];
```

**Right way is this:**

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"167884363345570/feed"] withPostVars:variables];
```

And i have solved the problem.